# How to run aggregates across partitions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I run a query like this in the portal, it runs just fine. But when I run it from the python SDK, I get “Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE ' for aggregates.". I want to run it across all partitions. Any suggestion on how to get it working from the SDK?

Thanks, 
Peter

SELECT 
    c.data.video.id, 
    COUNT(1) as nTraces,
    MAX(c.data.time) as lastReport
FROM c 
WHERE c.data.time > "2020-06-02T17:40:25.593141+00:00"
GROUP BY c.data.video.id

Answer (score 1):

According to my test,python sdk don't support `group by`.

Below is my test code:

```
query = "SELECT c.id FROM c group by c.id"
items = list(container.query_items(
    query=query,
    enable_cross_partition_query=True
))
```

Here is the error:

```
azure.cosmos.exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError: (BadRequest) Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Query contains 1 or more unsupported features. Upgrade your SDK to a version that does support the requested features:
Query contained GroupBy, which the calling client does not support.
```

Refer to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-cosmos-db-supports-group-by-for-queries-for-sql-core-api/),.net sdk and js sdk support `group by`.
So you can do this by using .net sdk and js sdk.

By the way,I search for the [python sdk release history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-python) and it doesn't mentioned supporting `group by`.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: a simple group by seems to work for me: SELECT t.data.video.id FROM Traces t GROUP BY t.data.video.id. I would expect the SDK to simply pass on the query to the service. it shouldn't need to do any custom processing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I create a container like yours.And I run the sql:`SELECT t.data.video.id FROM Traces t GROUP BY t.data.video.id` then still get the same error.My python sdk version is 4.0.0 and I find 'GROUP BY' in documents.py at the source of sdk.And I don't know sdk how to run the sql.But it seems not like simply   passing the query to the service.